# Can @Inject be used in a pojo

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-6

I am trying to use and understand CDI, when I use @Inject in a simple pojo class, it throws me NPE.

example 
Greeting.java

```
public Class Greeting {
 public String greet() {
   System.out.println("Hello");
 }
}
```

Test.java

```
 import javax.inject.Inject;
 public class Test {
   @Inject 
   private Greeting greeting;

   public void testGreet() {
    greeting.testGreet();
   }
}
```

When I call testGreet() it throws NPE, why is the greeting instance null. Does @Inject way of adding dependency only be used in container managed bean?
Note: jar is not the problem here.

Comment: You can inject a POJO, but the class to inject into has to be container managed (to let the container know on instantiation that he has to fill the `@Inject`-annotated fields).

Comment: somewhere else you must have method return Greeting with @ Produres annotation

Answer (score 7):

TL;DR:
@Inject-annotated fields are only populated for container-instantiated beans.

Long version:
The CDI container provides you a lot of utilities for easily injecting dependencies to your beans, but it doesn't work by magic. The container can only populate the annotated fields of a client bean if the client bean itself was instantiated by the container. When the container is instantiating the object the sequence of events is as follows:

1. Your bean's constructor is called.
2. @Inject-annotated fields (and some other
   annotations, @PersistenceContext and @EJB for instance) are
   populated.
3. @PostConstruct-annotated no-args method is called.
4. Your bean is finished.

You're facing a classic bootstrapping problem, how to move from non-container-managed code into container-managed code. Your options are:

1. Get access to an instance of BeanManager from your JavaEE container via JNDI lookup. This is technical and a bit clumsy.
2. Use a CDI extension library such as Apache DeltaSpike. (Example: `BeanProvider.getContextualReference(Test.class, false);`)
3. Modify your application to start in a situation where you can inject your Test class rather than calling `new Test();`. This can be done for example by setting up a startup singleton ejb, which calls your test in it's @PostConstruct-annotated initialisation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using DeltaSpike is a great idea in any case!

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaEE container, and than you need to define Greeting and Test as managed beans. After that you can inject one in another.

Try to take a look at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be implemented from Serializable for being injectable as a "CDI Bean"